# Simultaneous bulkinserts using ADO.Net against SQL Server, what indexes to chose?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

If I do simultaneous bulkinserts using ADO.Net against the same table using two different processes with separate connections each having a transaction with isolation level "ReadCommitted" against a table having:

- RowId:bigint identity
- FooId:uniqueidentifier PK Non Clustered (assigned upfront in code before bulkinsert)

With regards to simultaneous inserts, would it be better to:

- a) put a PK on RowId with a clustered index and unique key contraint index, non clustered on FooId
- b) put a unique key contraint index, non clustered on RowId

Any other tips?

Comment: As Kimberly Tripp explains in her blog post, [The Clustered Index Debate Continues...](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx), having a *good* clustered index (on something like an `BIGINT IDENTITY`) column is actually **beneficial** to your bulk inserts. Inserting into a well designed table with a well chosen clustered index is **faster** than inserting into a heap (table without clustered index) - so I'd say, go for option (a). Not sure if you need a NC on `Foo` - what for?

Comment: Foo is a "business key" and is used in queries and joins but can't be clustered.

Answer (score 3):

No matter which one you choose, you will have one of the indexes be in the RowId identity order. Both operations will attempt to insert rows in the same region (end of index) and thus will not be able to achieve minimally logging (ie. the fastest possible load). I strongly recommend you read [Data Load Performance Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

The obvious question is *why* do you want two concurrent bulk insert operations? More likely they will slow down each other rather than going faster. Achieving parallel fast load streams in a clustered+index scenario is quite difficult. Have you experimented with a single stream and TF610? If you are able to achieve minimally logged bulk inserts with a single stream, and use a large enough batch size, I expect it to be faster than two fully logged parallel streams.

Comment: I don't control it, since it's up to the consumer. They can have a workflow where two concurrent session starts bulkinserting data against same tables.